# How do i use Flutter Freezed package?

Tags: flutter, freezed, flutter-freezed

How do I use the [freezed 2.2](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) package in my flutter app?

Comment: There is a great how to section on the link you posted...

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the best tutorials which will help to understand the whole concept of `Freezed` and how it works.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUc95hhAWLo&ab_channel=MarcusNg

```
dependencies:
  freezed: ^2.2.0
```